# Does slow network or loading too much data affect onclick slideToggle() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `slideToggle()` function works well in some pages. It doesn't work in some other pages.

What I need to know is whether the ***slow network*** or ***loading too much data*** affects onclick `slideToggle()` function or not?

Comment: Your question lacks precision. Consider editing it by adding context, code, etc ... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, not in itself.  The load on your machine/device would affect `slideToggle`.  So loading too much data would generally add load to the device thus making everything slower / causing paging etc.  If you (for some crazy reason) make an ajax call then that would cause an issue but otherwise network would have no impact as it's all client-side so no network traffic to be waiting on.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your `slideToggle` function?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m , That's what I need to know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in itself. The load on your machine/device would affect slideToggle. So loading too much data would generally add load to the device thus making everything slower / causing paging etc. If you (for some crazy reason) make an ajax call then that would cause an issue but otherwise network would have no impact as it's all client-side so no network traffic to be waiting on.

-- @freedomn-m